Does Powertools for AWS Lambda can instrument DynamoDb calls?
I was wondering what should I use to isnstrument my code. I found here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-tracing.html#java-xray-sdk that I can use either AWS X-Ray SDK for Java or Powertools for AWS Lambda (Java). My biggest concern is the fact that I want to see if I can trace with Powertools how much does it take to run several methods and some calls to S3 or DynamoDB. I saw that I can use Utilis in order to instrument a code block under a subsegment (https://docs.powertools.aws.dev/lambda/java/core/tracing/). But for DynamoDB and S3 I am not sure because I found the section Instrumenting SDK clients and HTTP calls that says to use based on the function dependency so because of this I tend to think that they do not support direct instrumenting for DynamoDB and S3.

In your lambda function, can you following the example in x-ray doc to enable AWS Service requests tracing?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/scorekeep-lambda.html
